# get the current user like in the post query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores posts. I want to create a query to retrieve posts and if the current user liked this post. This is my query:

```
select *,CAST(iif(exists(select 1 from Post.PostLike where PostId=ps.Id and UserId=@UserId),1,0) as bit) as IsLiked
from Post.Post ps
```

Is there a query better than this?

Comment: Do you mean performance tuning like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444085/are-there-any-query-optimization-tools-for-sql-server)?

Comment: You'd probably get a performance increase from using `APPLY`, rather than a subquery in your `SELECT`. The former should be evaluated once for the dataset, where as the latter once for every row.

Comment: @vahdet yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT ps.*,
       convert(bit, CASE
                      WHEN psl.userid IS NULL
                        THEN 0
                      ELSE 1
                    END) isliked
       FROM post.post
            LEFT JOIN post.postlike psl
                      ON ps1.postid = ps.id
                         AND psl.userid = @userid;
```

And then create an index on `post.post.id` (unless it already has one, which should be the case for a primary key column) and an index on `post.postlike.postid` and `post.postlike.userid` (again unless such an index already exists, which might be the case it the columns are the primary key, which is reasonable).

```
CREATE INDEX post_id
             ON post.post
                (id);

CREATE INDEX postlike_postid_userid
             ON post.postlike
                (postid,
                 userid);
```

Or alternatively change the last one to

```
CREATE INDEX postlike_userid_postid
             ON post.postlike
                (userid,
                 postid);
```

if there are more users than posts.

Check the execution plan if the indexes help.